# Callback for intersection observer being called for images that are not intersecting

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

I have some images with a fixed height I want to lazyload. These images are wrapped in a component, `<LazyLoad />` which provide an intersection observer. In the main page, I use a few of these `<LazyLoad />` components. However, although I have 6 of these components and only one of them (the very first one) seems to be intersecting the view port, it's actually the first 4 images that are already loaded, so only the last two are lazily loaded. How do I get the observer to work as I expect it to?

The code is [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mo8jvz9oxp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes the `img` with an empty string. The page renders the images but ignore the `height` you've set on it. Which means that all the images are inside the viewport which trigger the observer. Rather than an empty string you can consider the `null` value. It avoid this issue. Here [your example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vo2y40lz5) updated.

```
getImgUrl = () => {
  return this.state.intersected
    ? "https://images.unsplash.com"
    : null;
};
```